# Objects on which my table depends in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a query to get the list of tables on which my table depends? I have already tried `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`, `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities`, `sp_depends, information_schema.routines`.

This gives the objects which depend on my table. These are the queries I have tried:

```
sp_depends 'dbo.buyer'

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.routines ISR
WHERE CHARINDEX('dbo.buyer', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) > 0

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id),* FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  
WHERE referencing_id =  OBJECT_ID('dbo.buyer')

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id),* FROM 
ims.sys.sql_expression_dependencies  
WHERE referenced_id =  OBJECT_ID('ims.dbo.buyer');

SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.buyer', 'OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.name 
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
INNER JOIN sys.tables as t 
ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables as t2 
ON fk.parent_object_id = t2.object_id
WHERE t2.name = 'yourTableName'
```

Answer (score -1):

Go through the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table

You can get details of
1. Object that depends on
2. Object on which {table} depends